# BinaryReader.Read does not throw IOException when the connection is lost

Tags: windows-phone-7, ioexception, binaryreader

I use HttpWebResponse.BeginGetResponse() method to make a request to my server. The request has AllowReadStreamBuffering set to **false** so that the data will not be buffered. In the "Request Complete" notification I do the following (no error handling code included):

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(result);
BinaryReader streamReader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream());

try
{
    while ((readSize = streamReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
    ...
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{   // NEVER GET HERE!!
...
}
```

My problem is that I cannot detect connection errors during reading data from stream (during the while loop). The behavior is very strange: it finishes to read all data that the OS has in the cache and then returns 'readSize = 0' as in the case of "end of stream".
I was expecting streamReader.Read() to throw an IOException exception **but it does not**!
I tried to find a **stream failed** flag somewhere but it seems that there is none (Stream/BinaryReader/HttpWebResponse). Please help!

I tested this by using three scenarios and all had the same behavior:

1. Using the phone-to-PC USB connection

   - Phone connected to Internet using the PC USB connection
   - After few streamReader.Read() successful calls I disable the PC network card
2. Using WIFI connection

   - Phone connected to Internet using WIFI connection
   - After few streamReader.Read() successful calls I power off the WIFI router
3. Using WIFI connection

   - Phone connected to Internet using WIFI connection
   - After few streamReader.Read() successful calls I remove WAN cable (so it has no Internet access).

Thank you!
Mihai

Comment: At this moment it is 16K but this has no relevance.

Comment: try making your own exception under the while loop, giving you more control of the situation...This may help you figure out what is going on more in depth.

Comment: won't you expect an exception on the first two lines of your code instead of the Read() method. You already end the get request, so i don't necessarily expect an exception there. I would expect it to happen in the EndGetResponse()

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting an exception then one option is to check the number of bytes read against response.ContentLength